# Use fetch to get HTTP results before the end of the request

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch

I'm trying to consume the `/api/stream` endpoint of a Drone 1.0 server. This endpoint keeps the HTTP connection opened and just streams new upcoming events to notify the consumer of events.

I tried with that piece of code using the javascript Fetch API

```
 await fetch("https://drone.company.com/api/stream/", {
    headers
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

This code works well, but the `then` callback is always called after the request has ended.

Is there a way I can make fetch a stream of the body received while the request is processing ?

Comment: no, that's not how fetch works

Comment: I just realized how basic my example is... But I also tried the requestType stream from axios that doesn't work neither for my use case. Will I really have to use sockets ?

Comment: not sure what you would use, I just know `fetch` is not the appropriate thing to use - though sockets looks like the right thing

Comment: @skybower's answer is a way togo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can read from `response.getReader()` like

```
let response = await fetch("https://drone.company.com/api/stream/", {
    headers
  });

const reader = response.body.getReader();

while(true) {
  const {done, value} = await reader.read();

  if (done) {
    break;
  }
  const text = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(value);
  console.log(`Received ${text}`)
}
```

we need to use `TextDecoder` since `value` contains Uint8Array data not text. [Is not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) by IE. `fetch` [is not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) either btw.

based on https://javascript.info/fetch-progress